# How can I add a css class to the 10 last entries of a mysql database?

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have a very simple PHP function, fetching all results (from two tables "Items" and "Categories" and displaying them on a single site (directly on index.php)

```
function fetchAllItems($pdo)
{
  $statement = $pdo->prepare('select Items.*, Categories.*
                              from Items
                              INNER JOIN Categories ON Items.ItemCategoryID = Categories.id
                              ORDER BY Items.ItemName ASC'
                            );

  $statement->execute();

  return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Item');
}
```

Now I want to add an icon to the left with css to the newest (= 10 last sql database entries / rows), but I don't know how to do.

As a PHP newbie my logic goes like this:

- Identify the highest id
- Subtract the number 10 of the above result / value
- Create an if-function that goes something like this: "if $highest_id = within the range of 'lastInsertId() - 10' then apply css-class 'new-item'" (sorry for writing this down like a sentence, not like a real if-function, but as mentioned I am new...)

But I don't really know where to start / go from here and googling for the last 3.15 hours did not bring me any further?!

Thank you.

Comment: Well the first thing you need to do is output them. It's there that you'd apply the class.

Comment: Order the query by ID in descending order with LIMIT 10 at the end.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY {FieldName} DESC`, So, The first 10 result will be identified as `New`. `{FieldName}` should be `Auto Increment`

Comment: You are currently ordering your query results by the item name, which I assume has no bearing whatsoever on an item being “new” or not. So what  _is_ that criterion for “new” actually? You should not abuse record ids to create any such order, that is not their job (that’s uniquely identifying the record, and nothing else), so you might want to first of all add a date column, if none exists yet.

Comment: And do you want to output your items in the order of their “newness” - or do you want to output them in a different order, so that the items marked as “new” are not necessarily all at the top or bottom of the list, or even consecutive?

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, the order should still be by name ASC, I only want to display a small icon that items can be recognized as "new" when scrolling through this list – as mentioned by you, the items marked with "new" don't necessarily are listed at the top or bottom.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson but then the user could only see these 10 items, but I want to display all (currently 246 items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply subtract 10 from the highest ID to get the 10th highest, because there can be gaps in the ID sequence.

To get the 10 highest IDs, use:

```
SELECT id
FROM Items
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Put these into an array `$first_10`, and then when you're displaying the results of `fetchAllItems` you can do:

```
if (in_array($row->id, $first_10) {
    $class = "newest";
} else {
    $class = "";
}
```